# Stackoverflow while deleting an entity

Tags: java, orm, eclipselink

I am using Eclipse link and I want to delete all entities with a clause. But when I am doing it I get StackOverFlow error.  Here is the method I use for deleteting. What is wrong in it ?

```
EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
       try {
             ACLEntry acle =  new ACLEntry();
            TypedQuery<ACLEntry> q = em.createQuery("DELETE  from ACLEntry acle  where        acle.acl=:acl ", ACLEntry.class);
            q.setParameter("acl", acl);

           } catch (Exception ex) {
            LOG.throwing("DAO", "removeAllACLEntries", ex);
        // em.getTransaction().rollback();
        }
          finally {
            em.close();
       }
           }
```

Here is ACLEnrty entity:

```
   /*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package com.cisco.onepk_web.entity;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Objects;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;

/**
 *
 * @author abondar
 */
@Entity
@SequenceGenerator(name = "aclE_seq", sequenceName = "aclE_seq", initialValue = 1, allocationSize=1)
public class ACLEntry implements Serializable {

 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator="aclE_seq")
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = ACL.class)
    private ACL acl;

    private Integer seqNumber;

    private String action;



    private String protocol;

    private String srcAddr;

    private String dstAddr;

    private String srcWcard;

    private String dstWcard;

    private Integer srcPort;

    private Integer dstPort;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public ACL getAcl() {
        return acl;
    }

    public void setAcl(ACL acl) {
        this.acl = acl;
    }

    public Integer getSeqNumber() {
        return seqNumber;
    }

    public void setSeqNumber(Integer seqNumber) {
        this.seqNumber = seqNumber;
    }

    public String getProtocol() {
        return protocol;
    }

    public void setProtocol(String protocol) {
        this.protocol = protocol;
    }

    public String getSrcAddr() {
        return srcAddr;
    }

    public void setSrcAddr(String srcAddr) {
        this.srcAddr = srcAddr;
    }

    public String getDstAddr() {
        return dstAddr;
    }

    public void setDstAddr(String dstAddr) {
        this.dstAddr = dstAddr;
    }

    public String getSrcWcard() {
        return srcWcard;
    }

    public void setSrcWcard(String srcWcard) {
        this.srcWcard = srcWcard;
    }

    public String getDstWcard() {
        return dstWcard;
    }

    public void setDstWcard(String dstWcard) {
        this.dstWcard = dstWcard;
    }

    public Integer getSrcPort() {
        return srcPort;
    }

    public void setSrcPort(Integer srcPort) {
        this.srcPort = srcPort;
    }

    public Integer getDstPort() {
        return dstPort;
    }

    public void setDstPort(Integer dstPort) {
        this.dstPort = dstPort;
    }

    public String getAction() {
        return action;
    }

    public void setAction(String action) {
        this.action = action;
    }


    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 5;
        hash = 67 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.id);
        hash = 67 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.acl);
        hash = 67 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.seqNumber);
        hash = 67 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.action);

        hash = 67 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.protocol);
        hash = 67 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.srcAddr);
        hash = 67 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.dstAddr);
        hash = 67 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.srcWcard);
        hash = 67 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.dstWcard);
        hash = 67 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.srcPort);
        hash = 67 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.dstPort);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        final ACLEntry other = (ACLEntry) obj;
        if (!Objects.equals(this.id, other.id)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!Objects.equals(this.acl, other.acl)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!Objects.equals(this.seqNumber, other.seqNumber)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!Objects.equals(this.action, other.action)) {
            return false;
        }

        if (!Objects.equals(this.protocol, other.protocol)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!Objects.equals(this.srcAddr, other.srcAddr)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!Objects.equals(this.dstAddr, other.dstAddr)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!Objects.equals(this.srcWcard, other.srcWcard)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!Objects.equals(this.dstWcard, other.dstWcard)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!Objects.equals(this.srcPort, other.srcPort)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!Objects.equals(this.dstPort, other.dstPort)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ACLEntry{" + "id=" + id + ", acl=" + acl + ", seqNumber=" + seqNumber + ", action=" + action +  ", protocol=" + protocol + ", srcAddr=" + srcAddr + ", dstAddr=" + dstAddr + ", srcWcard=" + srcWcard + ", dstWcard=" + dstWcard + ", srcPort=" + srcPort + ", dstPort=" + dstPort + '}';
    }






}
```

Comment: Oddly, this is the first time I encounter a stackoverflow OP on stackoverflow

Comment: Can you post some of the stack trace that shows what methods are being called?